# Update specific document mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to update an specific doument in my mongodb.

I have this structure in my document:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("4d5ad421515b9dd78c5000014"),
"_type" : "ArticlePage",
"body" : "<br />",
"browser_title" : "Your Look",
"created_at" : ISODate("2012-02-15T19:22:57Z"),
"excerpt" : "",
"meta_description" : "",
```

I want to change this: "_type" : "ArticlePage" to this: "_type" : "EventPage".

I tried looking in the official docs.

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>
   }
)
```

I just need to update specific fields in the document. This is just one, but I have around 30 more. So, if I can do it with one, I will do it wiht the other ones.

Comment: use the $set operator (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right, track the main thing you haven't gotten to yet is the `multi` options. By default `update` will only change the first document that matches the query. If you set `multi` to true it will update all documents that matches the query.

```
db.collections.update(
    {_type: "ArticlePage"},
    {$set: {_type: "EventPage"}},
    {multi: true}//This will make it happen for all docs that match the query
}
```

Comment: Thanks.

Actually, I just one change field by field. Because I have many different templates. So, I think if I use multi, I will change even the templates that I don't want right?

That's the reason, I need to select exactly the specific document and field.

Comment: @user3472955 I'm not entirely clear what you are saying in your comment, but this query will change all documents that have a `_type: "ArticlePage"` entry to `_type: "EventPage"`.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear.

I don't need to change all documents. Because, In the same document, I have some "_type" that I want to keep with "ArticlePage". In the document, I have 23 "ArticlePage", I just need to change 12. Keep the other ones.

Thanks

Comment: @user3472955 then you need to specify your query so that it only affects the 12 you want to change.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I need to specify the query for just 12 elements. But is exactly what I can't do. I trying to picking the "_id" in mongo and then, try to set up the new value but it didn't work

Comment: @user3472955 If you just have a list of `_id`s you can use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/) operator with the list, but ideally your query would be a bit smarter.